# Invert 'My billing and shipping address are the same' checkbox functionality in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, address

I need to do a little customization in checkout:

I want to change the functionality of the checkbox `My billing and shipping address are the same` in this way:

The label will be Need Invoice (already managed to do this)

Then if the checkbox is

- **Not checked**: I want to keep the same address for billing and shipping
- **Checked**: I want to chose another address or insert a new one.